# Setar valor padrão na criação de uma tabela em SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou estudando Linguagem SQL e estou tendo alguns problemas na criação de tabelas, não consigo setar um valor padrão numa coluna, sempre que aplico, indica erro de sintaxe. Alguém pode me ajudar? Não faço idéia do que está acontecendo... (Se houver mais erros e puder indicar, por favor, agradeço)

```
CREATE TABLE USUARIO
(

ID NUMERIC IDENTITY,

LOGIN VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE NOT NULL,

SENHA VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,

DTEXPIRACAO DATE NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT DF_DTEXPIRACAO DEFAULT(1900/01/01) FOR DTEXPIRACAO,

CONSTRAINT PK_USUARIO PRIMARY KEY (ID)

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE USUARIO
(
ID NUMERIC IDENTITY,
LOGIN VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
SENHA VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
DTEXPIRACAO DATE NOT NULL default '19000101',
CONSTRAINT PK_USUARIO PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Faltou apenas alguns detalhes na sua query, após alguns ajustes ficaria assim:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTE
(
    ID NUMERIC IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_USUARIO PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    LOGIN VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    SENHA VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    DTEXPIRACAO DATE NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_DTEXPIRACAO DEFAULT('1900-01-01')
);
```